GMail API asks for authentication every time - Python Script
I would like to receive and send mails from GMail using a Python script. I have orientated myself on the Quickstart.py script from Google.
https://github.com/googleworkspace/python-samples/blob/main/gmail/quickstart/quickstart.py
However, I have to confirm that the script is authorised to access my mail account each time I run it. A token.json is also downloaded each time, which is then used the next time the script is called, but that doesn't change anything. If I then agree, everything works.
I have already tried to set the project to publish in the Google Cloud, but that was unsuccessful.
As I want to run the script headless on my Raspberry Pi, the authentication must be automatic.
What do I have to do so that I can connect headless.

Did you have a chance to read about this article? OAuth 2.0 for TV and Limited-Input Device Applications, I do think that your use case fits its capabilities.
